# jQuery rotator jumps instead of fading from one to the other

Tags: jquery

I tried to code a simple jQuery rotator to display changing HTML content in a widget.

The widget itself works, and each div fades in and out, but they seem to overlap, resulting in both divs being shown for a split second.

How can I make it so that the visible div fades out, and after it's displayed as none, the other div starts to fade in?

```
function fadeNext() {
    $('#patient-stories .patient-story-single').first().fadeOut('slow').appendTo($('#patient-stories .inner'));
    $('#patient-stories .patient-story-single').first().fadeIn('slow');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9f2bh164/

UPDATE:

I've managed to get a bit closer, in that each div is fading out before the next one fades in, but it's not looping ie. going back to the start when all divs have been shown.

http://jsfiddle.net/9f2bh164/2/

SOLVED:

http://jsfiddle.net/9f2bh164/3/

Comment: Is this a practice example for yourself? You could just use a [rotator plugin](https://www.google.ch/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20rotator).

Comment: I chose not to use a plugin, simply to cut down on the unneccessary stuff and keep it lightweight. Plus it requires one less library to load!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the successive animations inside the previous one's callback to ensure they follow order.

```js
function fadeNext() {
  $('#div1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#div2').fadeIn('slow');
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as this makes out, as this then shows both of them and fades them both as one div - http://jsfiddle.net/9f2bh164/1/

Comment: Managed to get it working with a bit of fiddling, thanks for your answer, this steered me in the right direction!